# href # within index.html#(number) problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, hyperlink, href

My site is built around a coda slider which shows different divs when they are selected from the navigation menu e.g home is `www.mysite.com/index.html#1`, about us is `www.mysite.com/index.html#2`, and so on.

Within the about us div (#2) I have a sliding form which has four divs that display one after the other. The tutorial I followed to set up the sliding form said to use links like `<a href="#">Next div</a>` to allow the user to switch divs. But the links don't work within my site because the user is already at index.html#2 when they see the form.

I'm sorry that this is so confusing but how can I get the links to work? I just need another way of specifying links to the divs so that my site doesn't get confused with the links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The tutorial I followed to set up the sliding form said to use links
>   like Next div to allow the user to switch divs.

I think the tutorial means that you implement a JavaScript event on that  to switch the link, it looks like this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="switchDivs(); return false;">Switch next</a>
```

the **return false** is to prevent the link from working, but to invoke the JavaScript only.